# open shift mysql database connectivity issue

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

i have integrated mysql database with php application on openshift.here is the php code for connection to database.

```
$connection=mysql_connect("127.11.79.130","admini5ceFmG","PAf-447H4rNP") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

 mysql_select_db("android",$connection);
 $name='umair';
 $regid='942';

 $insert_records="insert into registration values ('$regid','$name')";
    $run_query=mysql_query($insert_records);
```

added all the credentials properly and tried even env variable method.it shows the correct application and database name in ssh shell but still getting this error.
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct. The problem is elsewhere. Either a firewall problem, MySQL server configuration problem, or MySQL simply hasn't started.

Answer (score 0):

check if mysql is running with the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u admini5ceFmG -p -h 127.11.79.130 status
```

also check your config file

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```